# Why does environ['wsgi.input'].read() block even though it is allowed by PEP-3333?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsgi

#### Issue

Here is a simple WSGI application that is supposed to print the Content-Length
and the request body in the header.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/plain')])
    content_length = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
    print('---- Begin ----')
    print('CONTENT_LENGTH:', content_length)
    print('wsgi.input:', environ['wsgi.input'].read())
    print('---- End ----')
    return [b'Foo\n']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref import simple_server
    server = simple_server.make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

When I run this application, it gets blocked at the following call: `environ['wsgi.input'].read()`.

I run the application using Python 3 interpreter and submit HTTP post request to it using curl.

```
lone@debian:~$ curl --data "a=1&b=2" http://localhost:8080/
```

The curl command gets blocked waiting for output. The python interpreter gets blocked at the `environ['wsgi.input'].read()` call.

```
lone@debian:~$ python3 foo.py
---- Begin ----
CONTENT_LENGTH: 7
```

As you can see in the output above, the `application()` function has got blocked after printing `CONTENT_LENGTH`.

#### Workaround

I know how to work around the issue: By passing the Content-Length header value to the `read()` call.

Modified code to workaround the issue:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/plain')])
    content_length = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
    print('---- Begin ----')
    print('CONTENT_LENGTH:', content_length)
    print('wsgi.input:', environ['wsgi.input'].read(content_length))
    print('---- End ----')
    return [b'Foo\n']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref import simple_server
    server = simple_server.make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

The curl command gets a valid HTTP response now.

```
lone@debian:~$ curl --data "a=1&b=2" http://localhost:8080/
Foo
lone@debian:~$
```

The `application()` function also completes its execution.

```
lone@debian:~$ python3 foo.py
---- Begin ----
CONTENT_LENGTH: 7
wsgi.input: b'a=1&b=2'
---- End ----
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2014 17:53:21] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

#### Question

Why does the `environ['wsgi.input'].read()` call block when `read` is called without any arguments?

The [PEP-3333](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#input-and-error-streams) document seems to imply it should work. Here is the relevant text.

> The server is not required to read past the client's specified
>   `Content-Length`, and **should** simulate an end-of-file condition if
>   the application attempts to read past that point. The application
>   **should not** attempt to read more data than is specified by the `CONTENT_LENGTH` variable.
>
> A server **should** allow `read()` to be called without an argument,
>   and return the remainder of the client's input stream.

I understand that the *application should not attempt to read more data than is specified by the `CONTENT_LENGTH` variable*. I am disobeying this directive. But the *server should allow `read()` to be called without an argument* and return me the entire input stream. Why isn't it doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it only implements PEP 333 and not PEP 3333.

PEP 333 didn't have the condition about simulating end of stream by returning an empty string.

In PEP 333 you would have problems if you tried to read more than CONTENT_LENGTH if the WSGI server supported HTTP 1.1 and request pipe lining (keep alive) was being used.

I would suggest you read PEP 333 and compare the language to PEP 3333.

Also read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/10/details-on-wsgi-10-amendmentsclarificat.html

where I describe the whole issue and so contributed to the change in the PEP when it was updated for Python 3.